# SQL Server database localization with EF4 and MVC3?

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, localization

Well, first of all - **I am NOT talking about strings localization using resource files**.

**I am talking about data in database tables**.

I need to have English and French version.

And I am using EF4 with in my MVC3 application with MS SQL Server.

Let's say I have tables with static data:

[image]

Is there any easy approach in grabbing language specific fields from the database instead of using

```
if(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == "en-CA")
{
    var titles = dbcontext.Competencies.Select(x => x.TitleEn);
}
else if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == "fr-CA")
{
    var titles = dbcontext.Competencies.Select(x => x.TitleFr);
}
```

everywhere in my app when constructing LINQ statements?

Of course real statements are not that simple :)

Couldn't find anything doable on the internet.

Only some crazy complicated stuff that takes weeks to develop and I dont have time for.

How do people usually do this?

Thanks.